# How to Set Visit File Keystroke to Ask Root Password If Needed in Dired Mode

Tags: dired, permissions

Trying here to accelerate `root` file editing via `dired mode`.

That way thought in somehow adjust `visit` file keystroke `f`, as default, to either ask for root password or to enter it as `root` automatically.

Would be a way to `/sudo::/directory`, but binded to `visit`, in a way that wouldn't be necessary to type `/sudo::` everytime before dired command, when necessary. Is desired only enter `f` in given root user directory and minibuffer automatically asks for password.

Any ideas on how could that be done?

Comment: Yes, it would be a way to `/sudo::/directory`, but binded to `visit`, in a way that wouldn't be necessary to type `/sudo::` everytime before `dired` command, when necessary. Would only enter `f` in given root user directory and `minibuffer` automatically asks for password.

Comment: Just adjusted as requested, @Drew.